# Datatable global search throwing occasional ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-5.5

I have a 2 pages with 3 and 4 datatables on them respectively.

I have a requirement to replace the default search box for each datatable with one global search box.

So far I have implemented this just fine, I have the global search box set and hide the individual search boxes like so:

```
//Other JS to initialise datatables with Ajax serverside processing

$(".dataTables_filter").hide();

$("#datatable-search").keyup(function() {
    $(".dataTable").DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

The datatables are using ajax calls to load information serverside.

When it was just one datatable, I didn't have this issue, but with the global search of all datatables I am getting the occasional ajax error - caused by a 500 error server side. 
Using the developer tools console, I can see which calls fail, but then I can open/run them just fine later.

The project uses Laravel and so checking the Laravel log, I see this:

> [2017-11-06 00:03:50] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.

This would indicate that I haven't set the application key in my `.env` file - however, I have. The rest of my application works fine, heck even typing slowly works fine - it would appear the volume of calls causes this to happen, but I cannot understand why...

I can readily recreate the issue just by hitting backspace quickly a few times.

I could just redirect the error to the console, but I'd like to try and solve the error first. The error is currently just in my local environment and I haven't tried it in production yet - although I assume I will face a similar issue.

I considered disabling the text input until the search for the current `keyup` finishes, but this is quite invasive and not very UX friendly.

What would be the best way to go about this? Could there be a way to 'queue' up the ajax calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give some time to the user to type.

```
// Typing timeout
var typingTimeout = null;
// On keyup
$("#datatable-search").keyup(function() {
    // Clear previous timer
    clearTimeout(typingTimeout);
    // Set a new timer
    var that = this;
    typingTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".dataTable").DataTable().search($(that).val()).draw();
    }, 200); // Execute the search if user paused for 200 ms
});
```

**Edit** : Small error corrected.

Comment: I quite like this idea, however it causes a console error when i start typing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined - tracing it back it comes from this line `$(".dataTable").DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();`

Comment: Ahh, duhhh. It's because the context of `$(this)` has changed. All good - this works great! Just had to swap `$(".dataTable").DataTable().search($(this).val()).draw();` to `$(".dataTable").DataTable().search($("#datatable-search").val()).draw();`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed that. You should also abort any active ajax requests. But I am not sure where you can get the ajax object.